# Is it legal to interface Microsoft Excel with my application?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, vba

I wrote a vb.net program which uses Microsoft Excel.

I want to sell my program.

If customers have already installed Microsoft Office in their computers is it legal to interface Microsoft Excel with my application?

Source:
https://www.visualstudio.com/support/legal/mt171547

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is legal **as long as you do not include the Microsoft software itself**. You can market however you wish since your probably using interop to communicate with Excel. If client needs the software they need to purchase that license.

Comment: @Codexer What does "as long as you do not include the Microsoft software itself" mean?

Comment: They mean exactly as it says. As long as you're not selling the product packaged with Microsoft Excel, you're good to go. The customer should not be able to download/install your product and alongside it get a free install of Excel. The customer has to buy their own copy of Office with which you then interface. I'm sure providing a link to download Office from Microsoft would be acceptable. You'll probably be able to, from your library/app, be able to determine what version of Office is installed, if any, and send the customer to the proper location.

Comment: @Markowitz What I mean is you **can't provide the Microsoft product itself** to the end user. You cant include Excel with your software...